# Swift: Trying to implement NSCoding

Tags: swift, uiimage, nscoding

Im trying to add NSCoding protocol to my custom class:

```
class Convo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var pic: UIImage

    override init() {
        self.name = "Dror"
        self.pic = UIImage (named: "NoPic.png")!
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.pic = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pic") as! UIImage
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.pic, forKey: "pic")
    }

}
```

But it pops an error at the line:

```
self.pic = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pic") as! UIImage
```

The error in the console is:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And the error in xcode is:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

And I have no idea what to do.

EDIT:
When running this code:

```
class Convo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var pic: UIImage!

    override init() {
        self.name = "Dror"
        self.pic = UIImage (named: "NoPic.png")!
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.pic = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pic") as? UIImage
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.pic, forKey: "pic")
    }
}
```

It compiles ok, but self.pic in the end is nil instead of UIImage (named: "NoPic.png")

Comment: Your code is very excitable with all those exclamation points all over the place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have required image in your Assets?
"NoPic.png"

Ok, here is some changes:

```
class Convo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var pic: UIImage?

    override init() {
        self.name = "Dror"
        self.pic = UIImage (named: "NoPic")
        super.init()
    }
```

it works for me, but you must be sure that the image exist in your assets. You can skip .png format

Comment: Now it says "Value of optional type 'UIImage?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: Yes I did add it to my Assets

Comment: Look now. Add "?" to stored property and remove the "!" and ".png" in UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Convo: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var name: String
    var pic: UIImage?

    override init() {
        self.name = "Dror"
        self.pic = UIImage (named: "NoPic.png")
        super.init()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.pic = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("pic") as? UIImage
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(self.pic, forKey: "pic")
    }
}
```